# Manipulating window created by process

Tags: c#

I'm quite new to C# and is faced with an issue. I wish to manipulate a window (resize, move) that I dynamically created through:

```
Process app = new Process();
app.StartInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe";   //just an example,
app.Start();                              //it will be more than just notepad
```

I understand that I can get the handle by `app.MainWindowHandle` but I can't obtain the form by `Control.FromHandle(app.MainWindowHandle)`. Hence, I can't set the new location nor size of this notepad.

Any idea on how do I manipulate the window then? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note that you didn't create that window. Notepad created it. What you're really doing is manipulating a window that *somebody else* created it. This is generally frowned upon. (It's like wearing somebody else's clothes.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notepad is a Win32 application, not a .NET Form. That's why you can't get a `Control` from it - it's not a control!

What you CAN do with the window handle is pass it along to Win32 functions that can manipulate Win32 windows. There's a whole host of them such as [`SetWindowPos`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to set window location (and see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190423/using-setwindowpos-in-c-sharp-to-move-windows-around) on using it from C#).

See more reference on [Window functions on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632595%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and use [PInvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/) as reference for calling these Win32 methods from C#.