# PrintDialog box in WPF screen

Tags: wpf

I am using PrintDialog box in my WPF screen. When I show the dialog, it aligns to the left of my screen. I need to align it to the center of my screen. How do I achieve this?

Comment: PrintDialog is not a WPF function

Comment: yeah I know it's a Windows control and I am using it to achieve printing functionality in my app using PrintDialog d = new PrintDialog(). I just want the dialog box to postion to the center. Is that not possible?

Comment: you might want to check this http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0470__Windows-Presentation-Foundation/PrintaWPFVisual.htm

Comment: thanks for the tutorial, but i am not printing any Visual. I just read a pdf file and send it for printing using printdialog.

Comment: There is no simple way to position your `PrintDialog` from within WPF. However, you can find out how to position the `Window` using the `SetWindowPos` method of the `user32.dll` from the [Using SetWindowPos in C# to move windows around](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190423/using-setwindowpos-in-c-sharp-to-move-windows-around) question here on Stack Overflow.