# FolderBrowserDialog Vista style - how to center screen?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, interop, winforms-interop

I am trying to user a this project which is adapted from the Vista Bridge sample on MSDN http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms756482.aspx.

```
      WPFFolderBrowser.WPFFolderBrowserDialog fbd = new     WPFFolderBrowser.WPFFolderBrowserDialog();
      fbd.Title = "Title";
      fbd.InitialDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;

            if (fbd.ShowDialog() == true)
                {
                }
```

All goes fine but i just want to center the browsing window and can't seem to find the needed property for this. If anyone has used it or knows about it, please give me a hint !

Comment: If you're not afraid of a little P/invoke, then Hans Passant has your answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576156/winforms-how-can-i-make-messagebox-appear-centered-on-mainform

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that WPFFolderBrowser doesn't expose that functionality.

The longer answer is that due to the power of open source you can edit [`WPFFoldererBrowser.ShowDialog()`](https://wpffolderbrowser.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#library/WPFFolderBrowserDialog.cs) to do what you want. The line you care about is

```
int hresult = nativeDialog.Show(GetHandleFromWindow(parentWindow));
```

You need to:

1. pull out the `GetHandleFromWindow(parentWindow)` portion
2. get the window handle pointer
3. follow the instructions in [the MSDN dialog box positioning documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644996.aspx#init_box), ([Using SetWindowPos in C# to move windows around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190423/using-setwindowpos-in-c-sharp-to-move-windows-around) will help you translate from the native code in the MSDN documentation to the managed code you want)