# Set position of window from launching application

Tags: c#, wpf, exe

I have a launching application that uses `Process.Start("MyExe")` to open another one of my applications, which is stored in an executable, and presents a WPF window.

However I also want to be able to set the position of the WPF on the screen from within the launcher program.  I have tried using `MoveWindow` but it's not working.

```
Process flash = new Process();

flash.StartInfo.FileName = appDirectoryPath + "\\" + OnScreenKeyboardExe;
flash.Start();
Thread.Sleep(100);

IntPtr id = flash.MainWindowHandle;
File.WriteAllText("D://errorlog.txt", id.ToString());
OperatingSystemBase.MoveWindow(flash.MainWindowHandle, 1000, 1000, 500, 500, true);
```

in errorlog file I got id 0. So may be I am not able to get process or something.

Comment: 'exe window' - is this a console window, or an actual WPF window (as your question tags suggest)?

Comment: @LordWilmore, it's an actual wpf window.

Comment: Can you please post the code where you attempted to use `MoveWindow`, along with any error that might have been thrown?

Comment: @LordWilmore, sure.

Comment: Slightly different approach, using `SetWindowPos` is explained here ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190423/using-setwindowpos-in-c-sharp-to-move-windows-around.  Might be worth a quick try.

Comment: If the call to `MoveWindow` fails then please check `GetLastWin32Error()`, to see whether there is anything reported of use in there

Comment: Ah, so if you're getting back zero for MainWindowHandle then that is your problem, and fortunately the web is full of people asking similar questions, so you might want to start looking there

Comment: @LordWilmore, when i put thread to sleep for 300 it works but it shows exe window and then goes to specified location.

Comment: Well yes, that will be the case.  That's why it's called MoveWindow and not StartWithWindowAt

Comment: What's the _actual_ problem you're trying to solve here?  Why are you doing this in the first place?  You may wish to have your own visual container open, and then open the new exe within that container, as explained here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/94a67da1-8143-4e37-86c0-4deab0d1ec93/c-run-exe-from-a-form-and-keep-the-exe-within-the-boundaries-of-that-original-form?forum=winforms

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are not waiting long enough for the program to start, before you try to move it.

I changed `Thread.Sleep(100)` to `Thread.Sleep(1000)` and it worked fine!

Comment: Yes, but in this case exe window firstly show and then flicks to new position. like show on main position and then goes to specified location.

Comment: And that is what you do in your code... You move your window to another position.